# Show that Riemannian manifold $M$ is contractible if the loop space $\Omega_{p,p}$ is contractible.

Tags: general-topology, riemannian-geometry, geometric-topology, morse-theory, loop-spaces

Show that Riemannian manifold $M$ is contractible if the loop space $\Omega_{p,p}$ is contractible.

The problem is from the following material. It contends that the result is by standard Morse theory. Please help me to understand details in this argument. Thanks!

> [*On Complete Open Manifolds of Positive Curvature*](http://www.jstor.org/stable/1970682?seq=1#fndtn-page_scan_tab_contents), Detlef Gromoll and Wolfgang Meyer, Annals of Mathematics, Second Series, Vol. 90, No. 1
>   (Jul., 1969), **pp. 83 (the last paragraph)**

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Probably you can write down an explicit contraction, but recall that $\pi_{k-1}(\Omega_{p,p}(M))\cong \pi_{k}(M)$. This comes from the path space fibration $\Omega_{p,p}(M)\rightarrow P(M)\rightarrow M$. This implies that $\pi_k(M)=0$ for all $k>0$. If $M$ is connected, this says that $M$ is [weakly contractible](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Weakly_contractible). Manifolds are $CW$-complexes, hence $M$ is contractible by [Whitehead's Theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Whitehead_theorem).